Insert clickable link within a line of text from another cell
So... i have a sheet keeping track of details for real estate properties. Of relevance here:
Street Address
Cross streets
City
And i have a MAP cell in which i've created a URL that links to a google map search, that uses the above mentioned 3 fields to create a search. The map cell contains this: =HYPERLINK("https://maps.google.com/maps?q="&B2&" "&C2,"Maps") – this displays as a blue clickable link. When you click on it it takes you to a google map search in your browser.
Currently i also have a FORMATTED field that combines Street + Cross streets in a way that I copy paste it into client emails. That cell looks like this: =I2&CHAR(10)&""&J2&"" – this produces text that looks like this:
115-117 Banker Street
Between Norman & Bedford Streets
What i'd like to do is INCLUDE the map in this client facing FORMATTED cell. However, I want this to be a clickable link. So Basically i'd like to be able to copy and paste this out of the FORMATTED cell:
115-117 Banker Street (map)
Between Norman & Bedford Streets
How can i incorporate the MAP cell into the FORMATTED formula in a way that it shows up as a clickable link, and not just blank text?
I hope this is understandable.

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. What you are looking for is not possible. One workaround is to use Google Apps Script.
